# How to fix this error?

Tags: contract-deployment

I have followed "HOW TO WRITE & DEPLOY AN NFT Part 1" and I was met with an error:
Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost (error={"name":"ProviderError","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="sendTransaction", transaction=undefined, code-INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS, version=providers/5.5.0)...

My deploy.js looks like:

```
async function main() {
  const MyNFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyNFT")

  // Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
  const myNFT = await MyNFT.deploy()
  console.log("Contract deployed to address:", myNFT.address)
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

Comment: Is there a balance on your account?

Comment: Yes. It seemed it's not a problem of balance on an account.

Comment: Can you include the contract if there isnt a balnce isue sometimes there is a problem with the contract